# Terrible node js API performance with very light usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, redis, graphql

We have a Node.js graphql api, and with light usage (2-3 reqs/sec) request times shoot up into the hundreds of milliseconds very, very quickly.

Our main data sources are Postgres (with pg-node) and Redis (ioredis), and we're making proper use of dataloader to avoid n+1. The Postgres and Redis queries themselves are very quick, this slowness is entirely within the node app itself.

It seems as though just about everything slows down very quickly, I don't think it's network or pg/redis related at all.

Comment: I think you have to show some code in order let someone else help you

Comment: I understand, but it's pretty difficult since I have no real clue as to what's causing these slow downs. This is my first big node app so there may be something fairly simple I'm overlooking!

Comment: If you do not want to make an effort and publish the code that you use, do not expect people to spend their time answering your question. After all, this would only be a low-value guess, like perhaps your code mismanages the connection, which would result in quick slow-down of the performance.

Comment: @vitaly-t It's not for lack of effort. If there were a specific piece of code running slowly then I would gladly share it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

What type of heroku dyno are you using?

The cheaper dynos are shared on EC2 instances so it could be that you're sharing with companies that use more bandwidth.

Also, you might want to look at the network performance. Heroku load balancers are also shared as well as their outbound traffic. We ran into an issue last year where our outbound calls to redis were taking a very long time because of that.

I'd recommend moving the your api to aws. It skips the dyno layer so you have much better performance.

Comment: standard 2x. I get similar issues (10-30ms redis responses) when running locally, so I'm not entirely sure it's heroku.

Comment: In fact I don't think it's network reqs at all. It seems like just about everything in the app slows down under light usage.

Comment: 10-30ms redis responses is normal when you take account network connection. How are you hosting redis?